# How sphinx decides which files should go in _source folder at build time?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to use `html_show_sourcelink` and `html_copy_source` to display the rst sources of my documentation files. From what I understood the files are copied in a subdirectory `_source` of the `_build/html` directory.

How does Sphinx decide which file should go there ?

I'm asking because in one of my project (https://github.com/openforis/sepal-doc) a whole folder is ignored, breaking the underlying "source" button.

Comment: If `html_copy_source` is true, all source files are copied to `_sources`: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_copy_source. If you need help with "a whole folder is ignored", please post a [mcve].